# why in the source code __find_if's __trip_cout calculate as (__last-__first) >> 2

Tags: c++

I don't understand why the stl source code `__find_if" 
__trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;` and in the next for loop call four time 'if' segment. It's hard to understand

```
template <typename _RandomAccessIterator, typename _Predicate>
  _RandomAccessIterator
  __find_if(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
            _Predicate __pred, random_access_iterator_tag)
  {
    typename iterator_traits<_RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type  
        __trip_count = (__last - __first) >> 2;

    for (; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)  
    {
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;

      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
    }

    switch (__last - __first)
    {
    case 3:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
    case 2:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
    case 1:
      if (__pred(__first))
        return __first;
      ++__first;
    case 0:
    default:
      return __last;
    }
  }
```

Why not just like this

```
__trip_count = __last - __first;
for(; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
{
    if(__pred(__first))
        return __first;
    ++first;
}
```

Like above this, I think it is no need the switch segment.
Can anyone answer my doubts?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is on some architectures it has a small performance increase. The cpu may even execute some of the instructions simultaneously without you knowing.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: @JVApen stl source code <bits/stl_alog.h> in wsl

Comment: Loop unfolding, to achieve better throughput performance

Comment: @florgeng It looks like loop unrolling, reducing branch prediction errors. I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the exact reason to introduce this, however, it does look like a classical vectorizing technique. To code seems to been written in a way that doing the predicate on the 4 consecutive elements would be more efficient.

I can recommend [Understanding Compiler Optimization - Chandler Carruth - Opening Keynote Meeting C++ 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnGCDLhaxKU) as background information on compiler optimizations as it explains in more detail why it ain't the best idea to do so.

Some pointers to take away for it (spoilers) are:

- Your predicate could be inlined, if it would be a complex lambda, the vectorization might not be useful and the loop body might not fit in the execution cache, which could slow down
- Your compiler knows about vectorization and loop unrolling, which is much easier to apply if you don't do it by hand

I would recommend to write:

```
__trip_count = __last - __first;
for(; __trip_count > 0; --__trip_count)
{
    if(__pred(__first))
        return __first;
    ++first;
}
```

Looking at the [git blame](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blame/c11858417f85c18cbac5c88f2b6b958916a08091/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L116) of the code, it's somewhere between 6 and 16 years old. Most likely, at that point, compilers didn't do the optimizations better than by hand. It might still hold, it might not.